# \underbrace at a strange place, spanning array columns

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, arrays

Take a look at the following code:

```
$$\begin{array}{rr|r|c|l}
vd_2:&\raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\overbrace{\phantom{b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}c^k}}^v$}}b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}&b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}&c^k&d_2\\
\mathrm{PW}(w):&\dots w_r c^{r+1-k}&c^k\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\underbrace{\phantom{w_{k-1}\hspace{4.17em}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}c^k\hspace{2\arraycolsep}\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots}}_{w_r}$}}w_{k-1}\hspace{4.17em}&c^k&\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots\dots
\end{array}$$
```

I would like to draw the `\underbrace` in a more elegant way. The main problem is how to make sure that `$c^kw_{k-1}$` is in the dead center of the column. In the proposed code, it has been done artifically: the empty space of length `4.17em` is added to the right of `$c^kw_{k-1}$`, where the value `4.17em` is obtained by trial-and-error. This works nicely in `12pt`, but if the font size is changed, it slides off the center. Even if there were not a problem with changing the font size, it would seem logical that there is a nicer way to accomplish this effect, instead of guessing the value `4.17em` (or whichever works for the particular font size) until a good enough pixel-precision is reached.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

While code snippets are useful, it is better to compose a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't use `$$ .. $$`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward to do using the `savepos` module from the [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref). It allows you to place markers (or labels) in the text and retrieve their coordinates (x and y) in small point (or `sp`) units. The code is also much cleaner without the box adjustments you used.

Taking your code, I've defined the labels `L` to denote the left-most entry in your `array` (as a frame of reference), `TL` and `TR` to be the left and right `\overbrace` coordinate in the top row, and `BL` and `BR` to be the left and right `\underbrace` coordinate in the bottom row.

Then I construct an invisible table before typesetting the actual table. The invisible is overlapped by the actual table using `\mathrlap` (to produce a right overlap in math mode) from the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). Finally, spacing is obtained by `\hspace`s as needed. Vertical alignment is rectified using `\strut`, since there is otherwise no content to adjust the height/depth above/below the `\overbrace`/`\underbrace`. Using `\mathstrut` instead results in slightly weaker vertical alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathrlap{\begin{array}{l}
    \hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{TL}sp-\zposx{L}sp\relax}\overbrace{\strut\hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{TR}sp-\zposx{TL}sp\relax}}^v \\
    \hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{BL}sp-\zposx{L}sp\relax}\underbrace{\strut\hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{BR}sp-\zposx{BL}sp\relax}}_{w_r}
  \end{array}}%
  \begin{array}{rr|c|c|l}
    vd_2: & \zsavepos{TL}b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k} & b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k} & c^k\zsavepos{TR} & d_2 \\
    \zsavepos{L}\mathrm{PW}(w): & \dots w_r c^{r+1-k} & c^k\zsavepos{BL}w_{k-1} & c^k & \widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots\zsavepos{BR}\dots
  \end{array}
\]

\[
  \begin{array}{rr|r|c|l}
    vd_2:&\raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\overbrace{\phantom{b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}c^k}}^v$}}
      b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}&b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}&c^k&d_2\\
    \mathrm{PW}(w):&\dots w_r c^{r+1-k}&c^k\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\underbrace{\phantom{w_{k-1}\hspace{4.17em}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}c^k\hspace{2\arraycolsep}\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots}}_{w_r}$}}
      w_{k-1}\hspace{4.17em}&c^k&\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots\dots
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}​
```

Above is new `zref` version, while your original construction is given below. Since this uses `zref` and positioning labels, you have to compile (at least) twice for the referencing to be correct.

Comment: Thank you. It works exactly as I intented. The only problem I have with it is that it suggests including two (I believe rather cumbersome) packages, and I have the described problem with only one figure in the whole article.

I see that `mathtools` can be avoided by drawing the `\underbrace` in the way I originally did, while determining its position using `zref` as you suggested. I have yet to think about whether to use this way, or to, as I later find out, replace `\hspace{4.17em}` with `\hspace{2em}\hspace{25.5pt}`—it turns out that this works quite well for other font sizes, too.

Comment: @bbasic: [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provided `\mathrlap`, which is a very small part of the package. It would be possible to extract *just* that part, or use `\rlap` instead (but then you have to escape to math mode manually). My solution, however, is fundamentally driven by [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) and therefore won't work without it.

Answer (score 2):

if you need it only sometimes then use a workaround with `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rr|c|c|l}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\overbrace{\rule{0.65\columnwidth}{0pt}}^v}\\
vd_2:           &  b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}       & b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k} & c^k & d_2\\
\mathrm{PW}(w): & \dots w_r c^{r+1-k} & c^kw_{k-1} & c^k       &\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots\dots\\[-0.5\normalbaselineskip]
                & \multicolumn{4}{r}{\underbrace{\rule{0.4\columnwidth}{0pt}}_{w_r}\quad}                  
\end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not really fit my needs. I want everything to be placed very precisely, while your idea introduces too many rather arbitrary parameters (`0.65\columnwidth`, `-0.5\normalbaselineskip`, `0.4\columnwidth`, and the `\quad` at the end is especially unsatisfying, since it makes to look like that the `\underbrace` encompasses four dots, not three as needed).

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been cross-posted to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/) and solved. As Thorsten pointed me to the cross-post here, I'll add my [TikZ underbrace solution](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=15987&p=64639#p64637) here too, based on `\tikzmark` which has often been used here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
  \node (#1) {\strut};}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{rr|c|c|l}
    vd_2:
      &\tikzmark{topleft}b_1\dots b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k}
      &  b_{n-l_{k-1}-2k+1}\dots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}
      & c^k \tikzmark{topright}
      & d_2 \\
    \mathrm{PW}(w):
      & \dots w_r c^{r+1-k}
      & \tikzmark{bottomleft} c^k w_{k-1}
      & c^k
      &\widetilde{w_{k-1}}\dots\dots\tikzmark{bottomright}
  \end{array}
\]
\tikz[overlay, remember picture, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] {
  \draw[decorate,thick] (topleft.north) -- (topright.north)
      node [midway,above=10pt] {$v$};
  \draw[decorate,thick] (bottomright.south) -- (bottomleft.south)
      node [midway,below=10pt] {$w_r$};
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Underbrace and overbrace]