# Underbraces in Matrix Divided in Blocks

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

How to put underbraces, inside the parenthesis of a matrix, to name both sides of the blocks?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\[
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\]
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling the code in my university server, where I can't install new packages.

Comment: Please provide a MWE next time. Furthermore, what packages do you have installed now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's another (TikZ-free) option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\undermat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}_{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

\[
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\undermat{A}{0 & 0 & 0} & \undermat{B}{0 & 0 & 0} \\
\end{array}
\right )
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest and elegant way I've seen to do it. Thanks alot. But how about vertical braces and down face braces. I really appreciate if you can provide these features.

Comment: This only produces nice results if all matrix entries have the same width. If one replaces the first zero with `x+y+z` the result looks really ugly.

Answer (score 5):

Your code was not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (It's missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Please make it a habit to provide one.

You should really consider using the `\tikzmark` macro for this. There are already a lot of answers regarding this `tikz`-based macro on this site. (AFAIK, a package is on the way to completion based on this macro by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey). For instance you can read the related question: [\underbrace at a strange place, spanning array columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35359/underbrace-at-a-strange-place-spanning-array-columns?rq=1) which you can tailor to the code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
  \node (#1) {\strut};}
\begin{document}
\[
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 &\tikzmark{upper1} 0 & 0 & 0\tikzmark{upper2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\tikzmark{lower1}0 & 0 & 0\tikzmark{lower2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}]
\draw[decorate,thick] (lower2.south) -- (lower1.south)
      node [midway,below=5pt] {Left block};
\draw[decorate,thick] (upper1.north) -- (upper2.north)
      node [midway,above=5pt] {Right block};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to compile this twice to see the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}[margin=1pt]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace{3-1}{3-3}{A}[shorten]
  \UnderBrace{3-4}{3-6}{B}[shorten]
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]