# How to create an array with both vertical and horizontal braces around the elements

Tags: arrays, brackets, braces

I want to create the matrix shown bellow in Latex.
[image: Matrix that I want]

I have the horizontal curly brackets figured out, I can use `undermat{}{}` for that. I do not however know how to insert the vertical curly brackets around row 1 and rows 2-4, or how to insert the centered caption bellow the array.

Can someone please help me do this?

Here is my code so far with the horizontal curly brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\undermat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}_{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

$$
\left [
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
\undermat{T1}{1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2} & \undermat{T2}{1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2} & \undermat{T3}{9.4 & 2.5} \\
\end{array}
\right ]
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: We assume `\undermat` is from [Underbraces in Matrix Divided in Blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102468/5764)?

Comment: @Werner  Yes, that is the method I used. It doesn't work for horizontal braces though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way, using regular extensible braces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\newcommand\undermat[2]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102468/5764
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}_{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\[
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \begin{array}{@{} r @{}}
      \text{Bias nodes}~\{\hspace{\nulldelimiterspace} \\
      \text{Nodes}~\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\null\\\null\\\null\end{array}\right.
    \end{array}
    \left [
      \begin{array}{ *{8}{c} }
        1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
        1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
        1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
        \undermat{T1}{1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2} & \undermat{T2}{1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2} & \undermat{T3}{9.4 & 2.5} \\
      \end{array}
    \right ] \\
    \mathstrut
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `@{}` to remove inter-column spacing. You may want to move the left construction closer to the matrix on the right using `@{\hspace{-1ex}}` (say). Your choice.

Since `\undermat` sets `\underbrace`s that are `\smash`ed, they add no vertical height to the matrices and therefore allows for the `\left[`...`\right]` construction to span only the visible matrix entries. However, this could cause the `\undermat`s to run into content following the equation. To avoid this, we place the entire structure inside another `array` and add a blank line at the bottom. This allows the `\smash`ed `\undermat`s to have some whitespace to sink into.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is the purpose of the `\newcommand\undermat[2]{` bit? The code works fine without that bit.

Comment: @Blue7: [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) does not supply `\undermat`, so I copied it from the [mentioned answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102468/5764).

Comment: Oh yeah, I have that bit in the header of my document. I forgot I put that there. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way of making the top vertical brace bolder so that it matches the brace underneath it? `bf{\left\{}` doesn't work.

Comment: @Blue7: Try using `\scalebox{1.4}[1]{$\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\null\end{array}\right.$}` instead of `\{\hspace{\nulldelimiterspace}`. Also make sure you have `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble, since [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is the package that provides `\scalebox`.

Comment: This works brilliantly! It looks great when used with your other suggestion `@{\hspace{-1ex}}` to move the braces closer.

Comment: It helped me. But one request: `\undermat` overlaps an equation following below. Any suggestion for handling it in a nice way?

Comment: @Jeon: I've nested the entire structure inside another `array` which allows you to add a blank row at the bottom. This ensures there's some whitespace the `\undermat`s can run into.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col]
\text{\itshape Bias Nodes}\hspace*{4mm} & 1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
                                        & 1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
\text{\itshape Nodes}\hspace*{4mm}      & 1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 4.1 & 6.3 & 7.1 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
                                        & 1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 1.2 & 1.4 & 3.2 & 9.4 & 2.5 \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\{}{1-1}{1-1}{.}[xshift=1.2mm]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{2-1}{4-1}{.}[xshift=1mm]
  \UnderBrace{4-1}{4-3}{T_1}[yshift=1mm,shorten]
  \UnderBrace{4-4}{4-5}{T_2}[yshift=1mm,shorten]
  \UnderBrace{4-6}{4-8}{T_3}[yshift=1mm,shorten]
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]