# Kbordermatrix and underbrace

Tags: bordermatrix, underbrace

I want to create a kbordermatrix with an underbrace and some text below. I tried it with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{
\kbordermatrix{ 
& 1 & 2  \\
1 & a & b \\
2 & c & d 
}}_{test}
\]
\end{document}
```

which gave me this output:

[image]

As you can see the underbrace also goes below the rowlabels since they are treated as an extra column. Is there a way of using an underbrace which is only below the actual matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102463/124842, you could write ...`2 & \tikzmark{lower1}c & d\tikzmark{lower2} ` ...  . Or the last example of http://latex.org/know-how/508-latex-tricks-xv

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thx for your answer. I found the first thread you linked but the solution there is not working with kbordermatrices. The solution in the article of your second link however does.

Comment: 1link works also`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
  \node (#1) {\strut};}
  
  \usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\kbordermatrix{ 
& 1 & 2  \\
1 & a & b \\
2 & \tikzmark{lowerT1}c & d\tikzmark{lowerT2} 
}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}]
\draw[decorate,thick] (lowerT2.south) -- (lowerT1.south)
      node [midway,below=5pt] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: ... you have to compile twice.